# xslt how to remove the parent tag and change attributes of a child tag in an xml doc

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an example xml like below

```
<map>
<topicref href="disclaimer_PUBLIC.dita" outputclass="Top">
    <fig>
      <image href="">
        qw
      </image>
      <image href="">
        q1
      </image>
    </fig>
  </topicref>
  <topicref href="DocID030323.xml">
    <fig>
      <image href="">
        qw
      </image>
      <image href="">
        q1
      </image>
    </fig>
  </topicref>
</map>
```

Now here I want to remove the tag `<fig>` and add attribute width=5cm to the underlying image tag whenever the topicref outputclass="Top" .
I want the output as below:

```
<topicref href="../Topics/dita" outputclass="Top">

      <image href="" width="5cm">
        qw
      </image>
      <image href="" width="5cm">
        q1
      </image>

  </topicref>
  <topicref href="DocID030323.dita">
      <fig class="- topic/fig ">
         <image href=""
        qw
      </image>
         <image href="">
        q1
      </image>
      </fig>
  </topicref>
```

I am trying to achieve this but can only do 1 operation at a time in an xslt.
how to combine both operations?

when I use

```
<xsl:template match="topicref[@outputclass='Top']/fig" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>

  </xsl:template>
```

the fig element is removed but can't change the attribute values.

and when I use

```
<xsl:template match="topicref[@outputclass='Top']/fig/image" >
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="width">
      <xsl:value-of select="'2.5'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>
```

even the fig element is copied.I want to perform both operations in 1 xslt.
Please help.

Comment: What happens when you add both templates to your stylesheet at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT

```
  <xsl:template match="topicref[@outputclass='Top']/fig">
    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="topicref[@outputclass='Top']/fig/image" >
    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="width">
            <xsl:value-of select="'2.5'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"></xsl:copy-of>
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map>
<topicref href="disclaimer_PUBLIC.dita" outputclass="Top">

        <image href="" width="2.5">
            qw
        </image>
        <image href="" width="2.5">
            q1
        </image>

</topicref>
<topicref href="DocID030323.xml">
    <fig>
        <image href="">
            qw
        </image>
        <image href="">
            q1
        </image>
    </fig>
</topicref>
</map>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The solution removes all the `<fig>` elements from the output which is not according to the expected result. Same is the case with all the attributes which are missing in the output. Please check the expected output and update the solution accordingly.

Comment: @AniketV Thank you, was obviously a bit to fast there... now it should be edited and correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this it will faster:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topicref[@outputclass='Top']/fig">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image[ancestor::topicref[@outputclass='Top']]">
    <image>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="width" select="'2.5'"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </image>
</xsl:template>
```